# Re-Signing a MobileSubstrate-dylib after a String-Hack?

Tags: ios, code-signing, cydia-substrate

I like to see the current Date in the statusbar of my jailbroken iPad (3rd Gen, 5.1.1), so I installed the Tweak "DateCarrier". Sadly, it has no configuration and uses MM/dd/yyyy as its format, which I don't like.

I found the format-string for this in the .dylib-file and tried simply changing it to dd.MM.yyyy in a hex-editor. The string obviously has the same length and is still null-terminated. Sadly, the altered version of the tweak crashes on launch.

I think this is a signing issue, but as I have no experience with Mac-software or iOS-Development I don't really know how to proceed.

Google pointed me to the tool "ldid", which claims to sign binaries, but it bails out with the error "unknown load command 7" on the dylib-file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me if it's even possible to get the altered library to load?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Your hints helped me find a solution too.

The `ldid` tool has an option `-s` to refresh the hashes from the modified binary. This apparently is able to *adjust* the signatures and now I am seeing the date as dd/MM/yyyy w/o the nasty crash message :)